# AWS Cloudwatch empirical cumulative distribution function

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, cumulative-distribution-function

I've a lambda in my code that logs the average execution time of a particular snippet of code.
Let's say that I'll be logging in Cloudwatch values like 180 ms, 179 ms, 180 ms, 3000 ms and so on.

Is there any way to show in a graph the empirical cumulative distribution function of these values?
In particular, on the X axis I'd like to have the values (from 0ms to 300ms) and on the y axis the cumulative percentage of logged points that are lower the particular value on the x axis.
Simply looking at this kind of graph, I need to be able to say that for 50% of the data, the execution time was lower than x milliseconds.

I've tried with gauge graph but they only show the average but I'm really interested in the cumulative aspect of the problem.
Is there any way of automatically create such a plot in Cloudwatch?